# A question about $\varepsilon$-$N$ proofs.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I have an expression of the form $$(|a_m - a_{n+1}| + |a_n| + |a_m|)$$
where $(a_n)$ is a sequence convergent to $0$ and $m\le n$. I want to show that my expression is less than $\varepsilon$ (fixed at the beginning of the proof) for some choice of $n,m$. Here's my attempt:

Since $(a_n)$ is convergent, it's Cauchy. So there is a $N_1$ be such that $$p,q \ge N_1 \implies |a_p - a_q| < \varepsilon /3.$$

Furtheremore, since $a_n \to 0$, there exists $N_2$ such that $$p\ge N_2 \implies |a_p|<\varepsilon/3.$$

Now, let $\max \{ N_1 , N_2 \} \le m \le n.$ Then $$(|a_m - a_{n+1}| + |a_n| + |a_m|) \le 3 \varepsilon/3 = \varepsilon.$$

Is this correct? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: You don't need $N_2$, from the choice of $N_1$ follows that $\lvert a_p\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon/3$ for $p \geqslant N_1$. Not that that makes it much simpler. Your proof is correct, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct. However, here's a method that I would think of as simpler:

---

By the triangle inequality, we note that
$$
|a_m - a_{n+1}| + |a_n| + |a_m| \leq |a_m| + |a_{n+1}| + |a_n| + |a_m|
$$
Now, choose $N$ such that for $k>N:|a_k|<\varepsilon/4$.  By selecting $m,n>N$, we have
$$
|a_m - a_{n+1}| + |a_n| + |a_m| \leq 
|a_m| + |a_{n+1}| + |a_n| + |a_m| <
\varepsilon/4+\varepsilon/4+\varepsilon/4+\varepsilon/4=\varepsilon
$$
I find that once you know that a sequence converges to a known limit, it is rarely useful to invoke the fact that it is Cauchy.